# How to lexographically compare two vectors of strings?

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop

I am doing a C++ exercise where I have to implement a class representing a weak version of a vector that holds a string. One of the requirements is to overload the < and > operator following the rules of lexographical comparison.

I've been reading up on the algorithm but I don't understand it at all or how to implement it. What makes a vector < than the other? What do I compare from the strings? The private variables are string *array, size, and capacity.

Comment: [Take a look at how cppreference explains it.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) Heck, they even give code samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strcmp(string a, string b) in '<' overloading implementation.

```
class ClassName{
  /*
  variables

  constructors and methods
  */

  bool operator<(ClassName obj){
    ClassName obj1;
    if(strcmp(obj.str , obj1.str)<0)  //less than zero as we are overloading "<" operator
      return true;     //read - www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp

    return false;
  }
};
```

Similarly the ">" operator can be overloaded

Comment: Seriously? Have you tried to compile this? This is neither C nor C++

Comment: Did I already mention `obj1` is default-initialized and presumably just empty?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a lexographical comparison between two sequences is that you sort the sequences first by their first element, and if necessary then by their second, etctera. That is to say, if `a[0]<b[0]` then `a<b`. If `a[0]>b[0]`, then `a>b`. But if `a[0]==b[0]`, then you look at `a[1]` and `b[1]`.

When the sequence is a sequence of characters (aka string), this is the common dictionary order. But the same algorithm works on any sequence of sortable elements.